# Multiple graphs with ggplot using the same y-axis

Tags: r, ggplot2, plot, visualization

For example, I have pseudo data:

```
set.seed(2023)
n <- 1000
df1 <- data.frame(
    Ratio = sample(LETTERS[1:4], n, TRUE),
    Wealthness = sample(LETTERS[1:3], n, TRUE),
    Cash = sample(LETTERS[1:5], n, TRUE),
    Variants = sample(letters[17:26], n, TRUE)
)
head(df1, 10)
   Ratio Wealthness Cash Variants
1      A          B    E        r
2      D          C    C        w
3      C          A    C        r
4      A          C    D        y
5      D          C    E        w
6      C          B    E        u
7      B          B    E        y
8      D          A    B        x
9      B          C    C        t
10     A          B    E        z
```

I know how to plot the needed graph with ggplot2 package, but only using one variable (for example, Ratio):

```
library(ggplot2)
color_clrs <- c(
    A = "white",
    B = "black",
    C = "black",
    D = "white"
)
fill_clrs <- c(
    A = "#1f3560",
    B = "#bfbfbf",
    C = "#f2f3f3",
    D = "#ff0000"
)
ggplot(df1, aes(Variants, fill = Ratio)) +
    geom_bar(position = "fill") +
    geom_text(stat = "count", aes(label = after_stat(count), color = Ratio), 
              position = position_fill(vjust = 0.5), show.legend = FALSE) +
    scale_x_discrete(limit = rev) +
    scale_y_continuous(trans = "reverse") +
    scale_fill_manual(values = fill_clrs) +
    scale_color_manual(values = color_clrs) +
    coord_flip() +
    theme_classic() +
    theme(legend.position = "top",
          axis.ticks.x = element_blank(),
          axis.text.x = element_blank())
```

Result:

[image]

But, I struggle to update it in such way, that it would plot all variables (in this particular example 3, but code should work for any variables list size). For all variables it should look the same, but combined in one plot only with one y axis because for all variables is the same variable "Variants", but with separate legends based on columns' name. Colors can be the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might want to reshape your data to a "long" format

```r
library(tidyr)

df1 %>% pivot_longer(-Variants)
```

Then use `facet_wrap` for the effect of a shared y-axis:

```r
library(ggplot2)

facet_wrap(~name)
```

Full code:

```r
ggplot(df1 %>% pivot_longer(-Variants), aes(Variants, fill = value)) +
  geom_bar(position = "fill") +
  geom_text(stat = "count", aes(label = after_stat(count), color = value), 
            position = position_fill(vjust = 0.5), show.legend = FALSE) +
  facet_wrap(~name) +
  scale_x_discrete(limit = rev) +
  scale_y_continuous(trans = "reverse") +
  scale_fill_manual(values = fill_clrs) +
  scale_color_manual(values = color_clrs) +
  coord_flip() +
  theme_classic() +
  theme(legend.position = "top",
        axis.ticks.x = element_blank(),
        axis.text.x = element_blank())
```

[image]

I imagine there could be tons of possible minor adjustments to the graph, you can go through the [facet](https://ggplot2.tidyverse.org/reference/facet_wrap.html) or [ggplot documentation](https://ggplot2.tidyverse.org/index.html) for reference if you want to know more.

Comment: @Bambeil I can imagine the graph would be so so crowded with legends. You just add more colors to `color_clrs` and `fill_clrs` for having a single legend with all the colors.